# .NET Framework 4.x with Vite.js React front end

Tags: reactjs, .net, vite

I am building an app for a client who **requires** the project to be build on **.NET Framework 4.8**.

So what I'm going to do is build a REST API with the framework and use a react app for the front end.

I decided to use Vite.js for bundling and for now I am building the REST API (.net) and the front end (vite+react) on separate directories. Then when I have to test I run "vite build" and move my dist folder to my .net project.

It's working for now but I don't know if this will work after publishing so my question here is: **is there a *better* approach to create a .net 4.x application with react front end?**

Comment: Usually I'd just set up the proxy settings in Vite's config so that the api requests get sent through to the .Net Rest API and use the dev command `vite`. That way you get the vite dev server and fast refresh which is a much nicer dev experience. For prod it's pretty much as you've described if you intended to run them as one app in IIS / Azure

Comment: @JacobSmit that's basically what I was looking for, thank you!